# Django models: Use multiple values as a key?

Tags: python, database, django, models

Here is a simple model:

```
class TakingCourse(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term)
```

Instead of Django creating a default primary key, I would like to use both `course` and `term` as the primary key - taken together, they uniquely identify a tuple. Is this allowed by Django?

On a related note: I am trying to represent users taking courses in certain terms. Is there a better way to do this?

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    requiredFor = models.ManyToManyField(RequirementSubSet, blank=True)
    offeringSchool = models.ForeignKey(School)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s at %s" % (self.name, self.offeringSchool)

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    takingReqSets = models.ManyToManyField(RequirementSet, blank=True)
    takingTerms = models.ManyToManyField(Term, blank=True)
    takingCourses = models.ManyToManyField(TakingCourse, blank=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)

class TakingCourse(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term)

class Term(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    isPrimaryTerm = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) option.

```
class TakingCourse(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('course', 'term')
```

It would be better if you do something like this, though:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    takingReqSets = models.ManyToManyField(RequirementSet, blank=True)
    takingCourses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, through='TakingCourse', blank=True, null=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)

class TakingCourse(models.Model):
    my_user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term)

    class Meta:
         unique_together = ('my_user', 'course')
```

Read about [one to one relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#one-to-one-relationships) and [extra fields on many to many relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).